# EhCache Cache Warming

Tags: ehcache

I have set [DiskStoreBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/configuration#diskstorebootstrapcacheloaderfactory). How to check it is really working?

```
  <cache name="systemService.getLatestPublishInfo"
maxElementsInMemory="5" eternal="true" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
timeToLiveSeconds="0" overflowToDisk="true" maxElementsOnDisk="100"
diskPersistent="true" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
<bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
  class="net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskStoreBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
  properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=false" />
</cache>
```

I did not observe anything difference from log after my restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

net.sf.ehcache.Statistics would give the count of DiskHits and MemoryHits. Ideally it should be zero if everything is loaded to the memory